# SQL equally distribute value by rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a single row wit Date_Start, Date_End and Budget.
The idea is get the amount of days between Date_Start and Date_End to present the budget equally distributed by days.

Example:

origin (date in yyyy-mm-dd):

```
Date_Start,Date_End,budget

2018-04-01,2018-04-10, 300
```

The result show be:

```
day,        budget
2018-04-01, 30
2018-04-02, 30
2018-04-03, 30
2018-04-04, 30
2018-04-05, 30
2018-04-06, 30
2018-04-07, 30
2018-04-08, 30
2018-04-09, 30
2018-04-10, 30
```

Do you have any idea how to do it by SQL? I'm working with BigQuery specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-04-01' Date_Start, DATE '2018-04-10' Date_End, 300 budget
)
SELECT day, budget / (1 + DATE_DIFF(Date_End, Date_Start, DAY)) budget
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(Date_Start, Date_End)) day
```

with result:

```
Row day         budget   
1   2018-04-01  30.0     
2   2018-04-02  30.0     
3   2018-04-03  30.0     
4   2018-04-04  30.0     
5   2018-04-05  30.0     
6   2018-04-06  30.0     
7   2018-04-07  30.0     
8   2018-04-08  30.0     
9   2018-04-09  30.0     
10  2018-04-10  30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that doesn't require a stored procedure, provided the SQL implementation supports WITH.
Sorry, I don't know whether BigQuery has such support, but I can illustrate with MariaDB 10.3.9.

```
CREATE TABLE t (date_start DATE, date_end DATE, budget DECIMAL(10));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (DATE '2018-04-01', DATE '2018-04-10', 300);

with recursive mydates (cdate,nextdate,b) as (
  select date_start AS cdate, date_end AS nextdate, budget/((date_end+1)-date_start) AS b from t
  union all 
  select cdate+1, nextdate, b
    from mydates
   where cdate < nextdate
)
SELECT cdate,b from mydates
;
```

The result will be what you asked for, but without error checks, for example it assumes that date_end is well ahead of date_start.